# Finding time slice for threads using gettimeofday

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, gettimeofday

I'm trying to find the time slice of a program, first I assigned to each of the threads an ID to help identify them in their `f` function. In the `f` function, I used the `timeval` struct to check for the start and finish times, subtract them from each other and multiply by 1000 to convert to ms.
The result I expected (for example on 2 threads) was an infinite loop that would print that time for each thread. The result I got was an infinite loop, only going through the second thread and the time is always 0 or 0.001ms (why?).
I'd appreciate hints on how I should think of the solution \ what I've done wrong?
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> //For gettimeofday()

int i; //Global variable to act as an ID for the threads
void *f(void *p);

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        perror("Illegal input");
        exit(1);
    }

    int num;
    num = atoi(argv[1]);
    int index[num];

    pthread_t arr[num];

    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        index[i] = i+1;
        pthread_create (&arr[i], NULL, f, (void *) &index[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<num; i++) //Wait for all threads to finish
        pthread_join(arr[i], NULL);
}

void *f(void *p){
    int pid = *((int *)p); //Thread ID
    struct timeval start, finish;
    double elapsedTime;

    while(1){
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        gettimeofday(&finish, NULL);

        elapsedTime = (finish.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0; //sec to ms
        elapsedTime += (finish.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
        fprintf(stdout, "Time slice for thread %d = %lf ms.\n", pid, elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

The output (infinite loop):

```
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.000000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
Time slice for thread 2 = 0.001000 ms.
```

Comment: Anyway, `gettimeofday` is wrong function here. Use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ..)`. `time is always 0 or 0.001ms (why?).` Why not? Is there something wrong with just 1us vs 0?

Comment: @KamilCuk I read about clock, if I understood it correctly, it's just a difference of using CPU time and real-time time. But I did try it as well, didn't work (that's why I didn't show the try in my question)

Comment: @KamilCuk I believe that time of 0 is impossible to get if things were running as they should have, since that would mean the program finished instantly which is impossible (and if it was super fast, then it would need at-least 0.000001 or some other fast time, no?)

Comment: How is it impossible? You are doing `gettimeofday(&start, NULL); gettimeofday(&finish, NULL);`. How much time can pass between two `gettimeofday` called _right after another_? I still do not understand: `to check for the start and finish time ... The result I expected (for example on 2 threads) was an infinite loop which would print that time for each thread` - There is no "finish" time, because there's an infinite loop. You want to print how much time has passed _since_ the thread started?

Comment: @KamilCuk It makes sense... I will try to find my mistake using what you've said, thanks. => (response to your edit) yes, that's what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int main() {
    // here we start
    struct timeval start;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    while(1){
        // here we are right now
        struct timeval now;
        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);

        double elapsedTime = (now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0; //sec to ms
        elapsedTime += (now.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
        fprintf(stdout, "Time passed since thread started %d = %lf ms.\n", pid, elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Note that calculating difference between two calls of `gettimeofday` makes little sense - the clock is not monotonic. In anything serious use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC` for a monotonic clock.

Answer (score 1):

A better measurement procedure would be to use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now)` or `clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, &now)` in a loop.  Whenever the difference between consecutive iterations is larger than some limit (say, 0.025ms or 25µs), you start a new period.  The period ends in the measurement before the next such bigger difference.

Here is an example program that lets you name the clock to be used, the number of threads, and the number of seconds to measure:

```c
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Maximum interval between iterations */
#ifndef  NS_PER_ITERATION_MAX
#define  NS_PER_ITERATION_MAX  25000    /* 25 us, or 1/40,000ths of a second */
#endif

/* Number of slots per second to reserve per thread. */
#ifndef  SLOTS_PER_SEC
#define  SLOTS_PER_SEC  1000
#endif

static inline int64_t difftimespec_ns(const struct timespec after, const struct timespec before)
{
    return (int64_t)(after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) * INT64_C(1000000000) + (int64_t)(after.tv_nsec - before.tv_nsec);
}

struct measurements {
    struct measurements *next;
    pthread_t            thread;
    clockid_t            clk;
    int64_t              ns_runtime;
    size_t               ns_max;
    size_t               ns_num;
    uint32_t             ns[];
};

void *measure_slices(void *payload) {
    struct measurements *const m = payload;
    const clockid_t            clk = m->clk;
    const int64_t              ns_runtime = m->ns_runtime;
    const size_t               ns_max = m->ns_max;
    size_t                     ns_num = 0;
    uint32_t *const            ns_array = m->ns;

    struct timespec            started, mark, prev, curr;
    int64_t                    ns;

    if (clock_gettime(clk, &started) == -1)
        return (void *)(intptr_t)errno;
    if (clock_gettime(clk, &mark) == -1)
        return (void *)(intptr_t)errno;
    if (clock_gettime(clk, &prev) == -1)
        return (void *)(intptr_t)errno;

    while (1) {

        if (clock_gettime(clk, &curr) == -1)
            return (void *)(intptr_t)errno;

        /* Ran for long enough? */
        if (difftimespec_ns(curr, started) >= ns_runtime)
            break;

        /* Interval between this and previous iteration */
        ns = difftimespec_ns(curr, prev);
        if (ns <= NS_PER_ITERATION_MAX) {
            /* Still within the same timeslice */
            prev = curr;
            continue;
        }

        /* We started a new timeslice. */
        ns = difftimespec_ns(prev, mark);
        if (ns > NS_PER_ITERATION_MAX && ns < INT64_C(4294967296)) {
            /* Skip the very first measurement. */
            if (ns_num > 0)
                ns_array[ns_num - 1] = ns;
            if (++ns_num >= ns_max)
                 break;
        }

        mark = prev = curr;
    }

    m->ns_num = ns_num - 1;
    return 0;
}

static int parse_clock(const char *src, clockid_t *dst)
{
    if (!src || !*src || !dst)
        return -1;

    /* Skip optional CLOCK_ prefix. */
    if (!strncasecmp(src, "CLOCK_", 6))
        src += 6;

    if (!strcasecmp(src, "REALTIME")) {
        *dst = CLOCK_REALTIME;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (!strcasecmp(src, "REALTIME_COARSE")) {
        *dst = CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (!strcasecmp(src, "MONOTONIC")) {
        *dst = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (!strcasecmp(src, "MONOTONIC_COARSE")) {
        *dst = CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (!strcasecmp(src, "MONOTONIC_RAW")) {
        *dst = CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (!strcasecmp(src, "BOOTTIME")) {
        *dst = CLOCK_BOOTTIME;
        return 0;
    }

    /* We deliberately omit CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID and CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,
       because they reflect CPU time used, and our algorithm needs a wall clock. */
    return -1;
}

static int parse_double(const char *src, double *dst)
{
    const char *end;
    double      val;

    if (!src || !*src || !dst)
        return -1;

    end = src;
    errno = 0;
    val = strtod(src, (char **)(&end));
    if (errno || *end)
        return -1;

    *dst = val;
    return 0;
}

static int parse_size(const char *src, size_t *dst)
{
    const char    *end;
    unsigned long  val;

    if (!src || !*src || !dst)
        return -1;

    end = src;
    errno = 0;
    val = strtoul(src, (char **)(&end), 0);
    if (errno || *end)
        return -1;
    if ((unsigned long)(size_t)(val) != val)
        return -1;

    *dst = val;
    return 0;
}

static int compare_uint32_t(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const uint32_t val1 = *(const uint32_t *)ptr1;
    const uint32_t val2 = *(const uint32_t *)ptr2;
    return (val1 < val2) ? -1 :
           (val1 > val2) ? +1 : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int64_t              ns;
    double               seconds;
    size_t               threads, n, i;
    clockid_t            clk;
    struct measurements *list, *curr;
    uint32_t            *allns;
    pthread_attr_t       attrs;
    int                  err;

    if (argc != 4 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *argv0 = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s CLOCK THREADS SECONDS\n", argv0);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program measures the named clock,\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       REALTIME\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       MONOTONIC\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "       BOOTTIME\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "in a tight loop, in order to determine how long such\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "a tight loop can run uninterrupted (technically, with\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "at most %.1f microseconds (%.3f ms) between iterations)\n",
                         NS_PER_ITERATION_MAX / 1000.0, NS_PER_ITERATION_MAX / 1000000.0);
        fprintf(stderr, "collecting statistics of such durations.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Output is the measured durations in nanoseconds.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return (argc < 3) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_clock(argv[1], &clk)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid clock name.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_size(argv[2], &threads) || threads < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of threads.\n", argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (parse_double(argv[3], &seconds) || seconds <= 0.010) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of seconds to run.\n", argv[3]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ns = (int64_t)(1000000000.0 * seconds);
    if (ns <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid number of seconds to run.\n", argv[3]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Number of duration slots per second per thread. */
    n = (size_t)(SLOTS_PER_SEC * seconds);

    /* Allocate a measurement structure per thread. */
    list = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        curr = malloc(n * sizeof (uint32_t) + sizeof (struct measurements));
        if (!curr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        /* Initialize. */
        curr->clk = clk;
        curr->ns_runtime = ns;
        curr->ns_max = n;
        curr->ns_num = 0;

        /* Prepend to list of measurement structures. */
        curr->next = list;
        list = curr;
    }

    /* Measurement threads don't need much stack. */
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 2 * PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);
    for (curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        err = pthread_create(&(curr->thread), &attrs, measure_slices, curr);
        if (err) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create measurement threads: %s.\n", strerror(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* This kills also the already running threads. */
        }
    }
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    fprintf(stderr, "Measuring ... ");
    n = 0;
    for (curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        void *retval = (void *)0;
        err = pthread_join(curr->thread, &retval);
        if (err) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Lost a measurement thread: %s.\n", strerror(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* Also kills still running threads. */
        }
        if (retval != (void *)0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Measurement thread failed: %s.\n", strerror((int)(intptr_t)retval));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        n += curr->ns_num;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Done; obtained %zu durations total.\n", n);

    /* Collate results. */
    allns = malloc(n * sizeof allns[0]);
    if (!allns) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot collate results: %s.\n", strerror(ENOMEM));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (list) {
        curr = list;
        list = list->next;
        curr->next = NULL;

        if (i + curr->ns_num > n) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Internal bug when collating data: buffer overrun.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        memcpy(allns + i, curr->ns, curr->ns_num * sizeof (uint32_t));
        i += curr->ns_num;

        free(curr);
    }
    if (i != n) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Internal bug when collating data: buffer underrun.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    qsort(allns, n, sizeof (uint32_t), compare_uint32_t);

    /* Output in increasing order. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)allns[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you save it as e.g. `example.c`, you can compile it to `ex` using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example.c -pthread -o ex` .  Run `./ex --help` to see the usage.

Here is an example output (durations between larger clock differences, in nanoseconds, in increasing order) when running `./ex BOOTTIME 4 1` on an i5-7200U with two cores with two threads each, so four threads of execution:

```
25346
30283
32421
32725
33492
35245
35840
36478
37728
37764
38316
39747
40843
41106
41460
42031
42086
42198
42234
42347
42352
42505
42535
42777
43297
43415
43491
43523
43537
43642
43766
43787
43966
43977
43983
43988
43988
43992
44020
44036
44054
44080
44093
44192
44255
44308
44465
44504
44576
44586
44618
44619
44651
44658
44712
44717
44773
44791
44794
44834
44857
45097
45509
45659
45874
45991
46003
46022
46024
46102
46106
46108
46121
46159
46176
46187
46216
46252
46279
46281
46644
47064
47188
47229
47276
47468
47619
47803
48882
48937
49229
49235
49291
49331
49364
49496
49574
49675
49717
49762
49782
49822
49835
49893
49907
49935
49975
49994
50341
50372
50398
51238
51273
51304
51424
51703
51773
51787
51837
51838
51912
55287
57287
59358
59934
60645
62583
65875
82664
91088
190836
229532
287851
288769
310045
329565
372843
423063
433414
434355
474231
669240
688068
774163
783945
798116
844045
878774
986042
996956
1099045
1116371
1273081
1277074
1345787
1362752
1473027
1533827
1661606
1661648
1681454
1681696
1930065
1952703
1967833
2001524
2032112
2044125
2049316
2235882
2332409
2602839
2602850
2603006
2817151
2898885
3062130
3921933
3927327
3965095
3970580
3978114
4069431
4097642
4238546
4513423
4579035
4641020
4803608
4911424
5032919
6012137
6039261
6270161
6300259
6303458
6310116
6557892
6737421
7660021
7671463
7732257
7732308
7732436
7732455
7939267
7971787
8031922
8050166
8197531
8534918
8677078
8728024
8808732
8814990
9235892
9449015
9741948
10012384
10806507
11361965
11556520
12587385
12953578
13038394
13858728
14278834
15041709
15810753
16062442
16737253
17377461
17377603
17377634
17377647
17377736
17377742
17377783
17377807
17378073
17378178
17378302
17378489
17378598
17378604
17378650
17379365
17379576
17545273
17545739
17545753
17546676
17876097
17877331
17877365
17877829
17878187
17878375
17878614
17878660
17879356
17879481
17879494
17879618
17879665
18044880
18044938
18045074
18045188
18045351
18045459
18045550
18046538
18859731
19947402
19951568
19960383
19961624
19962660
23957571
23963028
26022469
27927170
39508952
39778596
40246691
43238996
43275323
43973206
57182522
69860693
79694268
82876417
90479990
91137669
96605181
97441594
141011381
199029008
242310741
246159499
391260825
```

Note that these are in nanoseconds, or 1/1,000,000,000ths of a second; and 1 ms = 1,000,000 ns.  As you can see, there is no particularly typical "time slice" length; they vary from very short (perhaps cache effects, perhaps a kernel hardware interrupt) to 0.39 seconds.

https://pastebin.com/cvLfrWxw has the output of `./ex BOOTTIME 8 10` for a larger dataset.  With 8 threads, the 60 Hz refresh rate no longer comes up (probably because the scheduler then also switches to a different task, as there are much more tasks running than there are hardware threads).

As you can see, there is no typical duration (that a thread can run without being interrupted for longer than 25µs).

This is as I expected, since the current Linux task scheduler (CFS Scheduler) [has no time slices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.html?highlight=scheduler#some-features-of-cfs) in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find the time slice of a program, first I assigned to each of the threads an ID to help identify them in their f function. In the f function, I used the timeval struct to check for the start and finish times, subtract them from each other and multiply by 1000 to convert to ms.

This (the general idea) cannot work. Elapsed time can include:

- IRQs that are not task switches
- time slices that were cut short by the task blocking and not using the whole time slice (including blocking while waiting to acquire a mutex on `stdout` in the lower levels of a `fprintf()`).
- any number of tasks all having time slices (e.g. elapsed time might be the sum of 20 different time slices)
- any combination of the above (e.g. elapsed time might be the sum of 5 IRQs that interrupted the thread's time slice, plus 20 different partial time slices of different lengths).
- "migration" to a different CPU (e.g. ending a time slice on one CPU then almost immediately starting a new time slice on a different CPU).

For these reasons; any value you get for elapsed time can never be assumed to accurately reflect the time slice length; and (due to "high risk of accidentally repeating timing patterns") any "frequently repeated" value you get for elapsed time can never be assumed to accurately reflect the time slice length.

In addition; most operating systems don't have one fixed length time slice in the first place. For example, Modern Linux uses a "auto-diddling of a thread's priority that influences that thread's time slice length" combined with a tickless scheduler.